# Password protect a folder/directory in IntelliJ - Maven project

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, maven-3

I would like to know if it's possible to password protect a folder/directory in IntelliJ that contains a .properties file containing sensitive data like usernames and passwords. The project utilizes the Selenium framework and is written in Java. All of the test classes read from the .properties file stored under a 'resources' folder. The values in the .properties file are accessed by using the getProperties function and subsequently specifying the key name.

Any other means of password protection/encryption would be great as the main objective is to ensure privacy of sensitive information stored in the .properties file.

Please advise if more information is required.

I would appreciate any advice given. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you not store the encrypted value in propertiles file rather than password protect the folder?

Comment: Hi Darshan. I'm not sure how to go about doing that as I've tried encrypting the passwords using the online Base36 Encoder then saving the encrypted password in the .properties file. I then ran one of the test classes and the test failed because the encoded value is being used. i.e. MJgfoFCI for example instead of the actual password. I'm not sure how to have the password decoded before it's used.

Answer (score 0):

no way.but you can write an other IDE or a files manage soft.or plug-in

Comment: I have no idea how to write a plugin. I will do some research on that but for now I'm open to other suggestions/solutions.